# Creating adjacency list from file

Tags: python-3.x

I have been tasked with reading in the contents of a file and then creating a adjacency list from that.

Each line represents a edge in the graph and the file looks as follows:

```
0 1 
2 1 
0 2 
1 3
```

Thus far I have read everything in and now have a list that comprises of:

> [['0', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['1', '3']]

My question is how do I use the above to get an adjacency list that looks like the following:

> [[1;2]; [0;2;3]; [1;0]; [1]]

Please note: Very new to the Python language and I am not allowed to import anything.

Answer (score -1):

The following solution uses a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
l = [['0', '1'], ['2', '1'], ['0', '2'], ['1', '3']]
adjacencies = dict()
for edge in l:
    x, y = int(edge[0]), int(edge[1])
    if x not in adjacencies: adjacencies[x] = set()
    if y not in adjacencies: adjacencies[y] = set()
    adjacencies[x].add(y)
    adjacencies[y].add(x)
print( [sorted(adjacencies[_]) for _ in sorted(adjacencies)])
```

However, a more elegant solution would be to construct dictionary `adjacencies` directly while parsing your input file (`test.txt` in the following example):

```
def get_adjacency_list(filename):
    adjacencies = dict()
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            x, y = [int(_) for _ in line.strip().split()]
            if x not in adjacencies: adjacencies[x] = set()
            if y not in adjacencies: adjacencies[y] = set()
            adjacencies[x].add(y)
            adjacencies[y].add(x)
   return [sorted(adjacencies[_]) for _ in sorted(adjacencies)]

print(get_adjacency_list('test.txt'))
```

Note, that the values of dictionary `adjacencies` are of type [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which are transformed into lists due to sorting (via built-in method `sorted()`).

**IF** you would be allowed to import anything you should use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of ordinary Python dictionaries.